# Strength standards for elite Judo

Tags: judo, competition, strength

How strong does one generally have to be to compete at elite level at judo?

Comment: https://strengthlevel.com/

Answer (score 3):

**Judo Australia** has published the following [strength and fitness guidelines](https://www.ausjudo.com.au/athlete-development) for its cadet judoka (lifts in terms of 3 rep max):

> In this document are a series of tests you can use to check your progress with Gold, Silver and
> Bronze targets that are based on the standards achieved by elite Australian and International cadet
> judo athletes. **The Bronze targets are the minimum standards that you should be attaining in
> order to consider yourself a high-performance Australian judo athlete.**
>
> ...
>
> [image]
> [image]

---

The following website (link dead) had a similar breakdown of core strength exercises in three skill bands (data taken from [this site](https://exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/StrengthStandards), lifts in terms of 1 rep max):

> [image]

---

The **German Judo Federation** gives a similar [list of benchmarks](https://assets.judobund.de/public/uploads/djb-athletikkonzept_240821.pdf) for elite performance:

> [image]